# What to do with partial skeletons?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Version 0.44.12-r1.

After some years of fighting, I have a 200 squares **corpse stockpile** filled with mostly "partial skeletons". I don't really know if they are all dwarves or not and I wonder what I could/should or shouldn't do with them.

I thought that partial parts of a dwarf would be put in his/her tomb along with the main body. Is it not the case?

Comment: Have you confirmed that if you make them a coffin, their body parts aren't all stuffed in?  I thought that was what would happen as well.  You can also toss the skeletons in lava and make slabs to avoid ghosts.

Comment: I tried to check the names but I have too many coffin-ed corpses and partial skeletons and I can't match the names. I don't even know if the partial skeletons are from dwarves or pets or goblins or whatever... They have dwarvish names though e.g. Sibrek Zaludzakul.

Comment: Looks like its working again, I see partial skeletons being brought in the coffins area. Not sure why but it works now.